# ubuntu directory creation failure

Tags: ubuntu

When I run this command to make a directory:

> sudo mkdir -p /db/active1/data /db/active2/data /db/passive1/data

nothing happens and no directory is made and no error is returned. I tested a few statements and saw that when I included "/" in front of "db", the same problem occurred. where can I can to see if those 3 directories have been made, if they have been?

Answer (score 1):

With `ls -a /` you should see the 'db' directory and check if the command was executed.